# AF_XDP zero copy - Operation not supported error

Tags: linux, sockets, xdp-bpf

I am trying to enable AF_XDP zero copy mode and i see the error in Cent OS 8(kernel 4.18), but SKB mode and DRV mode with copy works fine. The driver is ixgbe 5.6.5 which supports AF_XDP zero copy as per the documentation. strace shows the failure is during bind

```
./af_xdp_user -d eth2 -z -q 1

bind(3, {sa_family=0x2c /* AF_??? */, sa_data="\4\0006\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 16) = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
```

The ethtool shows i have combined queues and not separate rx/tx queues. Is that a problem?

```
[root@localhost ~]# ethtool -l eth2  
Channel parameters for eth2:
Pre-set maximums:
RX: 0 
TX: 0
Other: 1
Combined: 63
Current hardware settings:
RX: 0
TX: 0
Other: 1
Combined: 9


[root@localhost ~]# ethtool -i eth2
driver: 

ixgbe
version: 5.6.5
firmware-version: 0x61c10001
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:00:06.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: From [the AF_XDP documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/af_xdp.html#faq) it doesn't look like combined queues would be an issue. Are you sure your driver supports zero-copy? It looks like [ixgbe got it in Linux 4.20](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=d0bcacd0a130974f58a56318db7a5ca6a7ba1d5a).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The stock driver does not support zero copy in 4.18. I am using the latest driver 5.6.5 from intel on Kernel 4.18. The intel documentation mentions that zero copy is supported from kernel 4.18.